# Spring restController return not found 404 on wildfly

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, ear

We have a rest project with Spring RestController like this:

```
   @RestController("/new")
   public class NewController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testControl() {
        return "works";
    }
```

But this project does not contain a boot class to start it. Instead there is a internal jar dependency that implements *AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer* spring class:

```
public class AbstractWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppSecurityConfig.class, DatabaseConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ServletContextConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/*" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new CORSFilter() };
    }
}
```

This rest project is compiled into an .ear file to be deployed into a wildfly server:
EAR pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>APP-INF/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <earSourceDirectory>src/main/app</earSourceDirectory>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>br.coop.unimed</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cmb-rest</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/api</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When a deploy this ear to wildfly, log says:

> 17:11:10,033 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   95) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
>   17:11:10,620 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   95) Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath:
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@8a0cb6a,
>   br.coop.unimed.config.security.SecurityWebApplicationInitializer@457597f,
>   br.coop.unimed.config.AbstractWebInitializer@1c37aaec]

and

> 17:11:23,815 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 95) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/api' for
>   server 'default-server'

**But when a try to reach http:localhost:8080/api/new/test or http:locallhost:8080/api/test, it returns 404 - Not found.**

Just to make it clear, i inherited this project from another company that ran this ear on another server that was the weblogic. As the weblogic is very heavy I am trying to run the same way on the wildfly server, but I was not successful despite the ear being successfully deployed on the server and the spring context is also registered correctly.

Does anyone have any idea what may be happening?

Comment: I say the other company also did not run this project :D lawl

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/new")
public class NewController {
  @ResponseBody
  @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String testControl() {
      return "works";
  }
}
```

Comment: i did. Nothing changes. Stiil not found.